# The distances from a point to the corners of a rectangle are $6$, $7$, $9$, and (integer) $d$. Find $d$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry

> Christina is standing in a rectangular garden. Her distances from the corners of the garden are $6$ meters, $7$ meters, $9$ meters, and $d$ meters, where $d$ is an integer. How to find $d$?

Can someone lend me your hand on it?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort. This should be added to the question rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

We have 5 unknown to determine, then we can guess at first $6$ opposite to $d$

[image]

with the following conditions

- $d^2-y^2=49-x^2$
- $49-w^2=36-z^2$
- $36-x^2=81-y^2$
- $81-z^2=d^2-w^2$

and then trying others configurations.

Comment: @MarkBennet Opsss...yes of course I fix that. That's a nice point, I add something on that.

Comment: @MarkBennet Do you thin we can guess at first what is the length opposite to $d$ form the given?

Comment: I think you have a good hint, provided you allow for the other cases. Look at your first and third equations together. Then it depends on the integer condition.

Comment: @MarkBennet Yes indeed I cannot see a way to define a priori which length is opposite to d. Thanks for your kind suggestions!

Answer (score 0):

Let $P$ be a point inside a rectangle $XYZW$ such that $\{PX,PY,PZ\}=\{6,7,9\}$ and $PW=d$ is an integer.  Suppose that the projections of $P$ onto $XY$, $YZ$, $ZW$, and $WX$ are $A$, $B$, $C$, and $D$, respectively.  Write
$$x:=XA=WC\,,\,\,y:=YA=ZC\,,\,\,z:=YB=XD\,,\text{ and }w:=ZB=WD\,.$$
Therefore,
$$PX^2=x^2+z^2\,,\,\,PY^2=y^2+z^2\,,\text{ and }PZ^2=y^2+w^2\,.$$
This gives
$$d^2=PW^2=x^2+w^2=(x^2+z^2)+(y^2+w^2)-(y^2+z^2)=PX^2+PZ^2-PY^2\,.$$
The only possible choices for $(PX,PY,PZ)$ such that $d$ is an integer are $$(PX,PY,PZ)=(6,9,7)\text{ or }(PX,PY,PZ)=(7,9,6)\,,$$
for which $d=2$.  Below is an example of a possible configuration.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We have a relation using Stewart's theorem for an arbitrary  parallelogram as follows "if ABCD is a parallelogram and P be any point in plane then $2AM^2 +2CM^2 - 2BM^2 + 2DM^2 $ = $ (AC^2 - BD^2)$ .

For a rectangle  AC =BD then by proceeding,  we can get desired un known.